# Using SWIG for Java, how can I selectively swig certain parts of a huge C/C++ header file?

Tags: java, c++, c, swig

I have some legacy C/C++ header files that I need to work with.  These header files are huge and I do not want to swig all of the elements.  Is it possible to swig only certain parts of that header file and if so, how would I go about it?

For example, here is a C header file called BigHeaderFile.h, with enum declarations:

```
#ifndef __HEADER_GUARD__
#define __HEADER_GUARD__

typedef enum _MYSTATUS {
    OK, NG, NONE
} MYSTATUS;

typedef enum _NOTINTERESTED {
    AVAL, BVAL, CVAL
} NOTINTERESTED;

#endif __HEADER_GUARD__
```

Below is my swig file:

```
%module MyNativeClass
%include "enums.swg"
%javaconst(1);

%include "BigHeaderFile.h"
```

When I run swig on the above, it generates two java classes MYSTATUS and NOTINTERESTED.  Is there a way to tell swig to only generate java enums for MYSTATUS only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost certainly looking for [SWIG's advanced renaming](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_advanced_renaming) feature.

You can start to solve this by using:

```
%rename("$ignore") "";
```

To cause SWIG to ignore all the declarations within your header file. Once you've done that you can then selectively re-enable wrapping of anything you see fit.

So your .i file becomes:

```
%module MyNativeClass
%include <enums.swg>
%javaconst(1);

%rename("$ignore") ""; // ignore all
%rename("%s") "MYSTATUS"; // except MYSTATUS

%include "BigHeaderFile.h"
```

You can specify what to un-ignore based on more than simple name matching, e.g. regex, namespace, type (class/template/enum/constness/...)

It turns out that my basic example above is almost identical to [an example in the docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_chosen_unignore).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Make a copy of the file BigHeaderFile.h, rename it to say BigHeaderFile.i, remove the parts for which you do not want swig wrappers, and in the swig file `%include "BigHeaderFile.i"` instead.
2. Before including the file BigHeaderFile.h in the swig file, use `%ignore NOTINTERESTED;` to tell swig to ignore NOTINTERESTED. Swig will then not generate wrappers for that class.

Note that in either case you probably need to add

```
%{ 
#include "BigHeaderFile.h"
%}
```

to the top of your swig file so that this line gets put in the wrapper code. Otherwise, it should not compile.